# Creating character variable as Factor

Tags: r

I am interested in turning a character variable with 72 options into a factor with four options so that the observations are separated into one of three zip codes (factors 1-3); if they are not one of those zip codes, I want the observation to get a 0 for zip. Thank you.

```
Fct2 <- factor(hs$zip, 1 == 35758, 2 == 35811, 3 == 35749, 0 ==....??)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zip = c(35758, 35811,35749,34234,34324)

Fct2 <- case_when(zip == 35758 ~ 1,
                  zip == 35811 ~ 2,
                  zip == 35749 ~ 3,
                  TRUE ~ 0) %>% as.factor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::recode` :

```
hs$zip2 <- dplyr::recode(hs$zip, `35758` = 1, 
                         `35811` = 2, `35749` = 3, .default = 0)
```